# Fitting second fragment to an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my Activity I ad a fragment dynamically which occupies a dynamic porportion of the screen (you can slide it up or down to cover the entire screen or just the bottom ~250dp).

I now want to dynamically add another fragment to the same activity but I need this new fragment to fit next to the first one. Meaning you can slide the first one still up and down but the second will then either stay behind the first or move to make room.

Google tells me to use the same fragment manager and just add a fragment but the same fragment manager has already done a commit (with the adding of the first).

Is there any way to achieve this? Thank you!

CODE:

In my activity onCreate I added a fragment called buildingFragment (blue)

```
    fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, buildingFragment, "BUILDINGPAGE");
    fragmentTransaction.hide(buildingFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

The buildingFragment animates itself in onCreateView so that most of its content is out of screen (bottom direction):

```
    // ANIMATE THE BUILDING PAGE TO PEAK FROM BOTTOM
    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(buildingPageView, "y", USEABLE_HEIGHT, USEABLE_HEIGHT-TOOLBAR_HEIGHT-VIRT_NAV_BAR);
    anim.setDuration(500);
    anim.start();
```

Now this BuildingFragment works and it can be slided up or down.
With a push of a button I want to add another fargment (red) to the activity but I need it to take the rest of the space on the screen that the BuildingFragment (blue) is currently not occupying.

No when I slide the BuildingFragment (blue) I need the second fragment (red) either to stay behind the Building Fragment or just make room by moving up or down. Either way is acceptable.

Here is an illustration:

[image]

Second question: 
If I DONT want to replace fragments but add a new one, how can I bring the older fragment on top of the new one?

Comment: Give portion of code snippet that you have tried. It will be lot more easier to understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks, added code and an illustration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) lib its may be help you that you want achieve.

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
    sothree:umanoParallaxOffset="100dp"
    sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
    sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
    sothree:umanoScrollableView="@+id/list">

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
       <!--LOAD FIRST FRAGMENT-->

    </FrameLayout>
<!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->
 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
       <!--LOAD SECOND FRAGMENT-->

    </FrameLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the lib. It is what I built already. The sliding panel is working. Questions rather is how do I fit two fragments inside an activity. Or if that is no possible, how to bring the first fragment on top of the second one created.

Comment: Add two place holder in both panel and load fragment in place holder from activity.

Comment: Sorry, can you please specify

Answer (score 0):

You can do commit as many times as you wish on a FragmentManager, BTW there is only one instance of `FragmentManager` that `getFragmentManager()` returns on each call. You can add a Fragment to any view any no of times.

So even if you have added a fragment, you can add same Fragment again to a view.

It is nothing but another instance of Fragment that will work as a isolated entity.

Comment: Okay, but then does android itself figure out to fit these fragments into the view? Because right now it just puts the second fragment on top of the first.

Comment: No, u need to specify where this fragment should appear.

Comment: If you add fragment same view where u added previous one, same case as you r doing then it depends on Parentview. For example: In LinearLayout both fragment will come side by side. In Relativelayout Next one will overlap previous one. like this.

Comment: I understand that. So my first fragment is added to the activity container and so is the second fragment. They all sit on the same container because I need the first one (blue) to slide over the activity (wich is a google map btw).

Comment: I think I figured it out by doing some simple math, but I still don't understand how to bring the older fragment ontop of the new one without destroying the old one. Any ideas?

Comment: Have different container for each fragment and then just keep those container wherever you want. For example: In your case, Container of old fragment should come on top.